# How to retopologize mouth of my character?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm retopologizing a mesh I sculpted and ran to a problem with retopologizing the mouth cleanly. The first time I retopologized it, it looked way too messy so now I'm redoing it, but I don't know how to do it cleanly.

How would I retopologize the teeth (the bumps) correctly? Are there any retopology strategies that I should be using for this?

Notes: *Shrinkwrap* and *Subsurface* modifiers are on

[image]

Messy previous attempt
[image: messy previous attempt]

Current attempt
[image: Current attempt]

Current attempt (in edit mode)
[image: current attempt (in edit mode)]

[image]